# Inline Content-type

Tags: 7, nodes

Is it possible with Drupal to create/edit other nodes of different content-types, when editing a node of one content type?

Example:

- Content-type Survey; has fields title, body and an x amount of
  questions.
- Content-type Question; has title and body

Rather than creating the question nodes separately and linking them with an Entity Reference when editing Survey (lots of back and forths, and can get quite cumbersome when a lot of surveys/questions). I would like to add the questions underneath the Survey form when creating/editing a Survey node.

I've used this before with other frameworks such as Django (called Inline), example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects and would be amazing and a great feature for UI/UX if Drupal could do this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have have found that [field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) does the job I need. Not perfect, but very decent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this in a sandbox right now: http://drupal.org/sandbox/rszrama/1181848
Supports only products right now.
I plan to implement the final UI (the add form below the table, better styling) this week, then promote it to the "Inline Entity Form" namespace.